# Что в коде не так? Python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачал все нужные модули для pttxs3 и сам модуль pttxs, но в первом же коде не могу выяснить причину. Гуглил минут 30 ничего не нашел

Comment: Какую версию `Python` Вы используете?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, эта ошибка специфична для `Python 3.7.6-3.8.1`. Помогает откат до более ранних версий. Фикс планируется в `3.9`.

Comment: Я использую последнюю версию

Comment: Попробуйте откатиться до [более ранних версий](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

Comment: ок, тоясть мне щас питон удалить потом заново установить 3.2 версию?

Comment: Удалять необязательно. У Вас может быть сразу несколько версий (только не запутайтесь). И да, `3.2` совсем уж старая :) Советую попробовать [`3.7.1`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-371/) или [`3.7.4`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/).

Comment: Каким образом я буду переключаться от одной версии к другой?

Comment: Указывая путь до интерпретатора конкретной версии. Также (если они прописаны в `PATH`) можно использовать команды вида: `python3.x`.